# Finding two points that intersect a rectangle on a line that is perpendicular to a line segment

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, 2d

I'm having the following problem:

Given:

- A rectangle with a defined height(Y) and width(X)
- The line segment given by the points A and B
- A point inside the segment C

Find the points D and E that:

- Intersect the rectangle
- Forms a line segment that goes through C
- Forms a line segment that is perpendicular to the segment AB

[image: Clarification image]

To solve this problem, I've tried first calculating the slope and creating a line function, but all answers that I've seen to get the intersection between a line and a polygon uses a line segment and not a line function. How can I solve this? Am I missing a better way to find a perpendicular line that doesn't require a function?

```
function getPerpendicular(ax,ay,bx,by,cx,cy,x,y){
    let a=bx-ax;
    let b=by-ay;
    let slope;
    let line;
    // Because if a==0 the slope is infinite
    if(a===0){
        line=function(y){
            return cx;
        }
    }else{
        slope= (b)/(-a);
        line=function(x){
            return slope*x+cy-cx;
        }
    }
    // Intersection with the line function?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get direction vector for AB line (your a, b)

```
xx=bx-ax;
yy=by-ay;
```

Get perpendicular vector

```
dx = - yy
dy = xx
```

Now perpendicular line has parametric equation (it is for reference, no need to implement)

```
x = cx + dx * t
y = cy + dy * t
```

first check for horizontal/vertical lines

```
if dx = 0 then
    return cx, 0, cx, Y

if dy = 0 then
    return 0, cy, X, cy
```

prerequisites: potential border positions

```
if dx > 0 then
   bx1 = X
   bx2 = 0
else
   bx1 = 0
   bx2 = X

if dy > 0 then
   by1 = Y
   by2 = 0 
else
   by1 = 0
   by2 = Y
```

in general case find parameters of intersection with horizontal and vertical edge

```
tx1 = (bx1 - cx) / dx
ty1 = (by1 - cy) / dy
tx2 = (bx2 - cx) / dx //should be negative
ty2 = (by2 - cy) / dy //should be negative
```

and get intersection for smaller parameter value for one end:

```
if tx1 <= ty1 then
   ix1 = bx1
   iy1 = cy + tx1 * dy
else
  iy1 = by1
  ix1 = cx + ty1 * dx
```

and for larger parameter value at another end:

```
if tx2 >= ty2 then
   ix2 = bx2
   iy2 = cy + tx2 * dy
else
  iy2 = by2
  ix2 = cx + ty2 * dx
```

now return both intersection points

```
return ix1, iy1, ix2, iy2
```

Comment: I'm having a few questions on the translation of this to javascript code. Firstly when you make the parametric equations you introduce a variable "t", where does this come from?

Comment: Every point on the line corresponds to some value of t. For line defined by two points as your AB, t=0 corresponds to point A, t=1 corresponds to point B, t=0.5  - to middle point, t>1 for points beyond B ans so on. I wrote parametric equation for reference, there is no need to impement it. But calculations for tx1 and so on are based on this principle